# Not seeing any plots showing up in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I suspect my inability to see any results from my attempts to plot (using ggplot in RStudio) are related to the fact that when I check `dev.cur` I get `null device`. Would love help figuring out how to get plotting working in RStudio on my M1 Macbook Pro running Monterey.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if the data set is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Wild guess: If you have a `dev.off()`. Try your code after removing `dev.off()`.

Comment: On a working system, so you have a normal state, before I do my first plot, I get `dev.cur` returning `null device`. After the first plot, it returns `RStudioGD `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been assigning my plots to variables, in which case they are not rendered at assignment time (and don't show up.) E.g.

```
plt <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + geom_point()
```

In which case rendering the plot simply required evaluating the variable

```
plt
```

Problem solved. Thanks to the commenters for getting me on the right path.